# join и order by

Tags: sql, join, group-by

Я использую модель MVC. Можно сделать 2 простых запросов SELECT без джойнов. В контроллере обратиться к первому запросу, например так:

```
$questions = $this->model("Test")->getAllQuestions();
```

В VIEW:

```
foreach($questions as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value->question;

    foreach($this->model("Test")->getAllAnswersByQuestionId($value->id) as $key2=>$value2) {
        echo $value2->answer;
    }
}
```

Но такое нарушит концепцию MVC. По этому я хочу сделать один запрос с join и не делать обращение к модели из view.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил. Есть 2 связанных по id таблицы:

**test_answers**

```
id,
question_id,
answer,
current_answer
```

**test_questions**

```
id,
question
```

**Делаю запрос:**

```
SELECT * FROM `test_questions` 
INNER JOIN `test_answers` 
ON `test_answers`.`question_id`=`test_questions`.`id` 
GROUP BY `test_answers`.`id`
```

**Получаю**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть дублирование вопросов. Возможно это нормально. Но как вывести вопросы без дублирования?

Comment: А в что вы, собственно, желаете получить от такого запроса?

Comment: Это нормальное поведение при условие, что на вопрос есть несколько ответов (вариантов ответов).

Comment: ок, предположим что дублирования нет. должно выбрать 2 строки? что должно быть в колонке answer для строки с id = 1?

Comment: Может автору нужно увидеть только вопросы у которых существует по 1 ответу?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю правильный подход к данной проблеме следующий. 
Строка

```
$questions = $this->model("Test")->getAllQuestions();
```

Обычно, в MVC возвращает список обьектов (будем называть такие обьекты Question).

На уровне модели нужно реализовать метод getAnswers у класса Question, который бы возвращал список из обьектов Answer для заданного вопроса. По сути этот метод делает тоже самое что и

`$this->model("Test")->getAllAnswersByQuestionId($value->id)`

в Вашем примере.

Тогда во view будет примерно следующее:

```
foreach($questions as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value->question;

    foreach($value->getAnswers() as $key2=>$value2) {
        echo $value2->answer;
    }
}
```

Если вы используете готовый ORM, там такой функционал идет обычно из коробки как one-to-many ассоциация.